# 6 servers only 2 ups

Tags: windows, unix

i have 6 servers - 2 unix and 4 wins. Connected 2 ups on 2 servers with com port. Is there any way to connect other 4 servers that if electricity go down all 6 servers will go down with other 2 same time.

Maybe anyone know how to do this.

Sorry for bad english language, but maybe anyone understand what I want.

In short way: 6 server with 2 ups, how to do this.

Thanks for anyone who will help me.

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "up" exactly? What kind of com port do you mean?

Comment: Initially I was confused too, but I believe "ups" refers to Uninterruptible Power Supply.

Comment: Pekka first of all thanks for amazing fast response, but where you found "up"? UPS - Uninterruptible power supply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you look at [Network UPS Tools](http://www.networkupstools.org/) (aka NUT), which as well as coming with the capability to do a controlled shutdown of most unix platforms has a [Windows client](http://csociety.ecn.purdue.edu/~delpha/winnut/) for unattended shutdowns.  It'll work with a large range of UPSs from various manufacturers.

I've been using NUT for years and it's never let me down.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what UPSs you have but APC sell software that you run on one machine that's attached to the UPS, then the power goes down this single machine tells all the others to shutdown - might that help?

Again depends on the make/model of course.

Comment: +1 `apcupsd` is free software that can accomplish this too, though the configuration is a bit tricky and there's no paid support I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4):

[NUT](http://www.networkupstools.org/) is a good solution for running a server/client environment for shutdown too if the UPSs aren't APC.  I like [apcupsd](http://www.apcupsd.com/) for APC devices.

Comment: Have the Unix servers monitor the UPS using NUT. Install the Windows NUT client on the Windows servers.  You will need to ensure the router is also on UPS so it can be used to communicate between the servers.

Answer (score 0):

For the Unix boxes you could probably put an SSH shutdown command in an appropriately named script in the rc2.d directory so that it is run when Unix exits run-level 2.

Can't help with Windows.

Another idea would be to use a custom RS232 splitter - but you might need to boost the signal voltages.

For APC UPSs there is "Powerchute network shutdown" (free download I believe)

The APC [Share-UPS](http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z5QCB_R0_EN.pdf) lets you "Connect up to 8 completely OS-independent servers to a single UPS"

Answer (score 0):

I am using the APC Powerchute Network Shutdown in my core data centre and it works well. The only requirement is that you have APC UPS's with the ethernet management module installed in the smart slot.